# How to get file size of external file in python?

Tags: python

I want to find the size of the mp3 file located on another website...

I tried using the following code but it only works for the files hosted on my server.

```py
import os
b = os.path.getsize("file_on_my_server.mp3")
print(b)
```

How to get the file size of the following file?

https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3

Comment: Awful duplicate: [Get size of a file before downloading in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/5909)

Comment: The first answer is too large. As I am a beginner, I can't understand. I just want simple code to do this... @Awful duplicate